# Может ли один поток завладеть 2 ресурсами сразу?

Tags: java, многопоточность, монитор

Читаю в книге:

> При попытке конкурирующего доступа к объекту, чей монитор имеет владельца, желающий заблокировать объект-ресурс поток должен подождать освобождения монитора этого объекта и только после этого завладеть им и начать использование объекта-ресурса. Каждый экземпляр любого класса имеет монитор.

А может ли поток владеть  сразу 2 ресурсами, которые он заблокирует? и если да, то как это реализуется?

Comment: А почему нет? Сначала блокировать 1 ресурс потом 2 ресурс, потом отпускать по очереди.

Comment: Что тут подразумевается под "ресурсом"? Поток определённо может захватить мониторы нескольких объектов путём вложенного входа в несколько `synchronized` блоков/методов.

Answer (score 2):

Под ресурсом в данном случае подразумевается объект, по которому происходит синхронизация.

---

Сам механизм синхронизации реализован в виде метки в заголовке объекта. Перед получением доступа поток должен установить в синхронизируемый объект свою метку. По окончании работы поток разблокирует ресурс, то есть снимает метку с объекта, и другие потоки могут его заблокировать.

Сам процесс установления метки происходит таким образом, что даже в случае одновременной попытки блокировки, только один поток сможет поставить метку и соответственно выполнить синхронизацию по объекту. В случае попытки установить метку на ресурс, который используется другим потоком, текущий поток блокируется до момента, когда заблокировавший объект поток снимет с него свою метку, то есть разблокирует его. (Я сильно упрощаю реализацию механизма синхронизации для большей простоты восприятия, про настоящую реализацию можно почитать, например [тут](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/Synchronization).)

---

Соответственно любой поток может установить множество таких меток на различные объекты, на которых нет меток других потоков.

Answer (score 1):

Поток может одновременно завладеть каким угодно количеством ресурсов, при условии, что все они находится в одном блоке синхронизации, и что весь доступ к ним в других местах также осуществляется синхронизированно с использованием того же самого объекта блокировки.

Comment: при таком условии дедлоки были бы невозможны по определению